# iPhone webapp: run JavaScript on orientation change

Tags: javascript, iphone, iphone-web-app

I have a webapp saved to the iPhone homescreen, and I need to run some JavaScript when the device changes orientation.

I tried this, but it only seemed to work in a desktop browser and not on the iPhone.

```
window.onresize = function() {
  alert('rotation change!');
};
```

Is there some special event I'm supposed to hook into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `onorientationchange`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this together with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  function reorient(e) {
    alert('rotation change!');
  }
  window.onorientationchange = reorient;
  window.setTimeout(reorient, 0);
});
```

Or you can just use `onorientationchange` in your code.

You don't need to use jQuery in case you dont need to know when the DOM document is ready.

Comment: You're not using jQuery for anything there except notification of when the DOM is ready, which isn't even needed in this case.

Comment: Well he gets it in case it is needed.

Comment: Added clarification to my answer.

Comment: What I'm just trying to say is there's no need to bring in a whole library like jQuery for something like this, especially when it brings little, no, or negative advantage.